# Android C2DM Source Code or Implementation

Tags: android-c2dm

I have a requirment to use Android C2DM functionality.

However, the restriction is that there should be no data that goes outside organization network.

Does the server side implementation send data to Google servers?

Is there an option to implement C2DM service within a closed network, where the data is not sent to Google servers?

Thanks,
RR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of C2DM is that you "Notify" the device that new data is available, and then your application is starting a sync (or something else, eg showing a message).
In general you don't submit the data (sometimes called payload) using C2DM. It is limited to 1024 chars only.
This way no "company" data is sent to Google.

Comment: i m not sure that its link working or not but its give u idea how to implement c2dm in our application..                     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033213/how-to-retrive-registration-id-and-send-massage-to-third-party-application-in-an